# AWS Amplify API Gateway cors error after using authorizer: aws_iam

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have API Gateway endpoints which execute lambda functions. I want to protect my api endpoints with using aws_iam as authorizer. I have a user pool with federated identities set up for this. However after implementing it into the cloudformation template I get an cors error calling it from my angular app with an authenticated user:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api endpoint url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

here is the code of my cf template:

```
create:
handler: functions/api-create.create
events:
  - http:
      path: get/create
      method: get
      authorizer: aws_iam
      cors: true
```

my lambda function looks like this:

```
export const create = async (event, context) => {


console.log('Create: ', event)
  console.log('Context: ', context)
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      product: "hallo"
    }),
  };

return response;
};
```

Without `authorizer: aws_iam` everything works fine and I get the expected response. Does anyone know what I could be missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it out myself. Here is what I did.

After creating resources for the GatewayResponsdefault errors that they also have the correct headers with this templates in my Serverless.yml file:

```
 Resources:
  GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
      RestApiId:
        Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
  GatewayResponseDefault5XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_5XX
      RestApiId:
        Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
```

The error I received changed to a 403 error. Now I enabled cloud watch logging for my api endpoint since I was calling the endpoint with an authorized user.

There I saw now the error:

```
"message": "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-east-1'. "
```

After a little trial and error I found our that since I am using amplify I had to pass in the region for the api on amplify configure like this:

```
Amplify.configure({


Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: awsExports.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: awsExports.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: awsExports.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: awsExports.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID,
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
        {
            name: awsExports.api.name,
            endpoint: awsExports.api.endpoint,
            region: "eu-west-1" // <-- This was missing
        }
    ]
}
```